# What is the difference between Object.assign and Object.setPrototypeOf in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Let's say I have an animal object with a `speak` function:

```
function speak() {
  console.log(this.sound)
}

let animal = {
  speak
}
```

And I have a dog with a `sound`:

```
let dog = {
  sound: "Woof!"
}
```

If I want `dog` to inherit `speak` from `animal` I can use `Object.assign` or `Object.setPrototypeOf`. They seem to produce the same results:

```
let luke = Object.assign(dog, animal)

luke.speak() // Woof!

let bruno = Object.setPrototypeOf(dog, animal)

bruno.speak() // Woof!
```

What is the difference and is one way considered the "right" way?

Comment: Well, one big difference is that you should never use `Object.setPrototypeOf`. If you want inheritance, use a constructor.

Comment: The main difference is that Object.assign will overwrite properties of the first object with properties from the second, where as Object.setPrototypeOf will create a [[Prototype]] from the first object to the second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Object. setPrototypeOf

```
 function(obj, proto) {
  obj.__proto__ = proto;
  return obj; 
}
```

## Object.assign:

```
function(target, ...varArgs) { // .length of function is 2
    'use strict';
    if (target == null) { // TypeError if undefined or null
      throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
    }

    var to = Object(target);

    for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
      var nextSource = arguments[index];

      if (nextSource != null) { // Skip over if undefined or null
        for (var nextKey in nextSource) {
          // Avoid bugs when hasOwnProperty is shadowed
          if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(nextSource, nextKey)) {
            to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return to;
  };
```

---

Thus , `setPrototypeOf` is just assign `__proto__` of target to source, However, `assign` loops through argument(i) keys and override its values by argument(i+1)  values according to keys.